# Why is this interpreter variable not understood?

Tags: osc, supercollider

I'm trying to loosely-couple OSC message bindings to the function that handles them:

```
f = {|msg| msg.postln};
OSCFunc({|msg, time, addr, recvPort| f(msg)}, '/2/push1')
```

I thought this was pretty straightforward. I could substitute f at any point, and therefore muck about the handling of messages from the path `/2/push1` at will.

But when I hit the button (sending a message with path `/2/push1`), I get an error saying:

```
Message 'f' not understood.
```

So I'm guessing `f` has a different meaning within the scope of the function declared in the call to `OSCFunc`. I guess it has a different `Environment`?

I also tried putting the function in a regular variable:

```
(
var myFunction = {|msg| msg.postln};
OSCFunc({|msg, time, addr, recvPort| myFunction(msg)}, '/2/push2');
)
```

But this results in the same error.

Is there a way around this? Surely I don't have to place an entire function body within `OSCFunc` every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your problem is just a SuperCollider syntax issue - it lies in what you've written here:

```
  f(msg)
```

I think that you're hoping this "invokes" the function `f` with `msg` as an argument. However, SuperCollider's syntax isn't quite like that - it actually interprets that as being an equivalent way of calling `msg.f()`, which is why it throws an error saying that `msg` knows no `f` message. Instead, you need to use the `value` message on your Function:

```
  f.value(msg)
```

I can't find a tutorial that spells this out right now, so instead here's a link to [the Function helpfile](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/Function.html).

Comment: Holy crap! `f = { |x| x }; f(2);` produces the same error. I was convinced it was related to scope. I've been learning SuperCollider for about 9 months, but that has utterly curveballed me.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled around and found this:

```
f = {|msg, time, addr, recvPort| msg.postln};
o = OSCFunc(f, '/2/push1');
```

This works fine. Notice also the assignment of the call to `OSCFunc` to a variable. This enables me to 'de-register' the binding by calling:

```
o.free;
```

Comment: This is not the answer to the question (see Dan's), but it did kind of solve the problem for me. :)